# Extract and download HTML5 table as pdf,excel in Angular 4 CLI.?

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-cli

I need to extract and download my HTML5 table as Excel sheet, pdf in Angular 4 CLI. How I can do that? Kindly help me to solve these issue.

Comment: What is "your table"? A data-bound HTML5 table?

Comment: Yes normal HTML5 table. how do I download that table as excel and pdf.?@mbnx

Answer (score 1):

Both PDF and Excel are pretty complex file formats. Of course, exporting a table to such a format is not supported out of the box.

On server-side languages, there is a much better support for generating them, as more mature libraries are available. 
However, if you want to create PDFs from client-side Javascript, you can take a look at https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

To go the server-side way, you would implement some process like:

- Serialize table data to JSON
- Write an Angular service calling a server-side REST endpoint passing the serialized table data
- Generate the PDF/Excel file on server-side, whatever technology you use
- Move the generated file to some server-side folder accessible by the web-server for static file delivery
- Return a download link as REST response.